# Move DbSet<TEntity> properties to a Separate Class in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Here is what I have currently in MyContext class

```
 public class MyContext:DbContext
 {           
        public  DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public  DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
 }
```

What I want is to place all these `DbSet` properties into a separate file and just have one statement on `MyContext` class to add all `DbSet` from that separate file.

Comment: What's the point? The best you can do is a partial class as @Igor suggests. Ultimately, the `DbSet` props have to be part of your context class; using partial classes just let's you split it into separate files. However, that's generally an anti-pattern. A class and all of its functionality should be glanceable. Having to track down various partial implementations and piece them together in your head only makes your code harder to work with and understand.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Basically we are using some third party template  , and my idea is to have our DbSet and Fluent API into separate file, not to mesh our DbSet/Fluent API  with DbSet/Fluent API that  comes from the template.
Thank you !

Comment: You can't do partial classes across assemblies. Maybe inheritance instead.

Comment: okay , but we do have DbContext.cs file which comes from template so is it okay to hvae partial class for that DbContext file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a partial class and define the `DbSet<T>` properties there.

**MyContext.cs**

```
public partial class MyContext:DbContext
{           
}
```

**MyContextProperties.cs**

```
public partial class MyContext:DbContext
{           
    public  DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
}
```